Approximating an arbitrary set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with countable unions of cubes?
Let a neighborhood of a set $R\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be any $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\bar{R}\subseteq \langle U\rangle$, i.e. such that the closure of $R$ is a subset of the interior of $U$.
Question: For every pair $(R,N)$, with $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$  a neighborhood of $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a countable union $U$ of cubes (of any sizes) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $R\subseteq U\subseteq N$ and $N$ is a neighborhood of $U$?

EDITS / ADDITIONS:

Fixed and simplified the question in response to comments. (EDIT: Simplified more in response to further comments.)

Some context of my interest in the question: I'm currently trying to prove that a version of the parental Markov condition for regions of Minkowski spacetime entails a certain condition about the boundaries of regions. More specifically, I want to prove that, whenever all regions are screened off (rel. to some probability function) by any "thick parent" from everything outside of their causal future, then all regions are also screened off, by any thick boundary, from everything in their complement. My current proof idea presupposes a positive answer to a question closely related to the one I'm asking here. I'm happy to provide more details if interested.

What I've tried: the best I could muster so far is looking for counterexamples (and failing to find one). Any tips on how to approach trying to proving the result would also be greatly appreciated!



Can you provide some more context, e.g. what's your motivation for this question, and/or what have you tried?

Do you require $R$ to be connected? Otherwise, if I understand correctly, I think $R = \bigcup_{i = 0}^\infty B((i,0,...,0); 1/(i+3))$ and $B = \bigcup_{i = 0}^\infty \big(B((i,0,...,0); 1/(i+2)) \setminus B((i,0,...,0); 1/(i+3))\big)$ (where $B(p;r)$ is the open ball centred at $p$ of radius $r$) should be a counterexample, since the balls become smaller and smaller until you can't squeeze anything from a (fixed) set of tiles between $B((i,0,...,0); 1/(i+3))$ and $B((i,0,...,0); 1/(i+2)))$. However the set of tiles could be very weird too. So now I'm not 100% sure.

What if I add unused tiles to my set of tiles? For example, if I take ${\Delta, \nabla_\text{int}, R}$, so I can just take $U = R$, but I never use $R$ in the tiling?

Thank you for your responses!!
They made me realize that I hadn't completely nailed down the right question. First, I was mistaken about wanting a fixed non-zero limit on the size of the cells (which was implicit in the finiteness constraint on the tile set). Second, it turns out the tiling aspect isn't as central to my concern as my initial formulation of the question implied. Third, you're of course right that my initial formulation allowed for trivial answers like you highlight in your third comment. I've edited the question now, and moreover simplified it to be about cubes specifically.

I think the new version of the question now resists your two counterexamples.

Your notion of "thick boundary" is cumbersome and difficult to work with. Consider replacing it with the more standard one: A subset $U\subset R^n$ is a neighborhood of $R$ if the closure of $R$ is contained in the interior of $U$. Then you take $B=U\setminus R$. Every such $B$ will be a "thick boundary" in your sense, but easier to work with.

Thanks @MoisheKohan! I did as you suggested.

This becomes essentially a classical result in topology, going under the name normality for topological spaces. Let $d$ denote the metric on $\mathbb R^n$ corresponding to the $\ell_\infty$-norm. Thus, each $r$-ball with respect to the metric $d$ is a cube. The complement $C$ to the interior of $N$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ disjoint from the closure of $R$. Thus, for every $x\in \bar R$,
$$
d(x, C)=\inf\{d(x,y): y\in C\} >0. 
$$
Now, consider the collection ${\mathcal A}$ of open balls (actually, cubes)
$$
B(x, \frac{1}{2}d(x,C)), x\in \bar R.$$
This is an open cover of $\bar R$ by cubes disjoint from $C$. This cover admits a countable subcover ${\mathcal A}'$ (it is a good exercise, you can also read about Lindelöf spaces here). Lastly, take $U$ to be the union of the open cubes in ${\mathcal A}'$. It is clear that $U$ itself is contained in the interior of $R$ (since it is disjoint from $C$). I will leave it to you to check that the closure of $U$ is still disjoint from $C$ (this is why I divided by $2$ in my choice of radii).

Awesome, thank you!
I'm not quite sure how to start with proving that $\square$ has a countable subcover. Wikipedia just gives the answer away I suppose: any metrisable space that's separable is Lindelöf, so that makes $\mathbb{R}^n$ Lindelöf; it then immediately follows that $\square$ has a countable subcover.

Since the question as stated is now answered, I'll activate the tick. But I'm also interested in a generalization of the result: would it still go through if we replace cubes with (possibly more than one type of) convex polyhedra, capable of tiling $\mathbb{R}^n$. Feel free to impose various additional simplicity constraints on the polyhedra. Do you have any insight into this?

@Jens: You can use any convex bounded polyhedra for this purpose.
